# Sharepoint How to identify your current site is rootsite or subsite (level of subsite)?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom

I use "`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`" to detect the site url.

- From root site: `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, the result is "http://mywebsite:8888"
- From subsite level 1: `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, the result is "http://mywebsite:8888/subsite1"
- From subsite level 2: `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, the result is "http://mywebsite:8888/subsite1/subsite1_1"

How to identity your current site which you are surfing is root site or subsite by javascript? If subsite, which level of subsite is it? The solution is only javascript and only bases on the site url.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl`.

If `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` equals to `/` then you are definitely in the root site.

In the subsite, the value of `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` would be `/subsite1`.

In the sub-subsite, the value of `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` would be `/subsite1/subsite1_1`.

Another option would be, to check if `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` equals to `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`. This will be true only in case of the root site. So,  `if(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl == _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl)`, then you would be in the root site.

To detect the level of subsite, you can try it as below:

```
var value = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

var level = value.split('/').length -1;
```

Comment: Good idea for detecting root site and sub site. But I want to go deeper: if current site is sub site, which level of sub site is it?

Comment: if my root site is "mywebsite:8888/sites/mynewsite", variable "_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl" is "/sites/mynewsite" and your code is incorrect.